# C++ Function templates call itself and get stuck in recursion

Tags: c++, templates

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename ...__T>
struct CTest {
};

template<typename __T, typename ...__Ts>
struct CTest<__T, __Ts...>: public CTest<__Ts...> {
};

template<typename ...__T>
void func(const CTest<__T...> &);
template<typename __T, typename ...__Ts>
void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &);

template<>
void func(const CTest<> &obj) 
{
    printf("no data\n");
}

template<typename __T, typename ...__Ts>
void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &obj)
{
    printf("obj->data\n");
    printf("call %lx\n", func<__Ts...>);
    func<__Ts...>(obj);
}

int main()
{
    CTest<int> b;
    printf("func<>'s addr: %lx\n", func<>);
    func(b);
    return 0;
}
```

I want `func<>` to be call when `__Ts` is empty. However, `void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &obj)` recursively calls itself when `__Ts` is empty. The address printed in `printf("call %lx\n", func<__Ts...>)` is correct, which equal to `func<>`.

Changing the definition of `void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &obj)` as below can solve the problem. Very weird.

```
template<typename __T, typename ...__Ts>
void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &obj)
{
    printf("obj->data\n");
    printf("call %lx\n", func<__Ts...>);
    auto p = func<__Ts...>;
    p(obj);
}
```

Why the function template calls itself while the address is correct? I am a beginner of C++, is it a C++ rule? Thank you for your help.

*The enviroment is WSL, ubuntu 22.04, g++ 11.4.0, std=c++20.*

Comment: what is the code supposed to do? why is `func` recursively instantiating itself? I am certain that if you tell us why you wrote the code we can show you an easier way

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai But I explicitly call `func<__Ts...>`, and `CTest<__T, __Ts...>` inherit from `CTest<__Ts...>`.

Comment: ok, my initial understanding was off. I still dont completely understand it. Nevertheless I still think it would help if you explain what the aim is

Comment: Obligatory reminder that identifiers containing `__` or starting with `_[A-Z]` are reserved. Also the correct format specified for pointers is `%p`, and you should cast them to `(void *)`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The above code is a example. I found this problem when trying implement a tuple. I want to overload `operator==` for the class.

Comment: template recursion is only very rarely needed nowadays. You dont need it to implement `operator==`. Read about fold expressions

Comment: nevertheless very interesting quesiton. I would know how to fix it, but I cannot explain where exactly your code goes wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for suggesstion. I am a beginner of C++ and know much few code specifications. Nevertheless the codes work when I use point p, which exactly stores the address of `func<__Ts...>`. But the directly calling `func<__Ts...>(obj);` is wrong.

Comment: you need to get rid of the identifiers starting with `__`. It works until it does not and then it is a potentially terribly hard to find bug. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`func<__Ts...>(obj);` - here, despite you manually specifying the template arguments, the compiler still performs deduction and appends one extra type to the pack, based on `obj`'s type. Apparently this gets priority over converting `obj` to a different type.

`auto p = func<__Ts...>; p(obj);` - here you prevented template argument deduction; template arguments get baked into `p`'s type when deducing the `auto`, and then aren't touched again.

One way to fix this is `func(static_cast<const CTest<__Ts...> &>(obj));`.

---

There's a lot of weird things in your code, starting with

```
template<>
void func(const CTest<> &obj)
```

This is a explicit specialization of the first `foo`. Probably not what you intended. You end up with two overloads of `func` as following:

- 1st overload: `template<typename ...__T> void func(const CTest<__T...> &)` - declared but not defined for some reason.

  This one has the explicit specialization:

  - `template<> void func(const CTest<> &obj)`
- 2nd overload: `template<typename __T, typename ...__Ts> void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &obj)`

Specializing function templates is usually best avoided. Just make that overload non-template:

```
void func(const CTest<> &obj) {}

template<typename __T, typename ...__Ts>
void func(const CTest<__T, __Ts...> &obj) {...}
```

Comment: `func(static_cast<const CTest<__Ts...> &>(obj));` solve this problem, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `func<Ts...>(obj)` can still deduce arguments. When `Ts...` is an empty pack, you *are not* calling `func<>`. You need to ensure that you pass a `CTest<Ts...>`, not a `CTest<T, Ts...>`.

```
template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
void func(const CTest<T, Ts...> &obj)
{
    printf("obj->data\n");
    printf("call %p\n", static_cast<void *>(&func<Ts...>));
    func(static_cast<const CTest<Ts...> &>(obj));
}
```